# Expressing a typeclass with associated types and constants?

Tags: haskell, generics, typeclass

I'm trying to work out how to implement the concepts of associated types and constants for a typeclass in Haskell.

As practice, I am trying to make a typeclass for [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) nodes. A node has the given traits:

- Can be compared to other nodes (i.e. implements `Eq`, `Data.Hashable`)
- An associated function, `neighbours`, provides a list of neighbouring nodes (i.e. `neighbours :: Node -> [Node]`)
- Has a heuristic function, which provides a "distance" between nodes.
- The aforementioned distance is an *associated type* of sorts, which must be `Num`
  and `Ord`. It *cannot* simply be hardcoded to use `float` or something of that nature, as the concept of "distance" could have different precision requirements or even use something like manhattan distance on a 2D integer grid.
- Has associated values for a distance of "Zero" and "Infinity" (although 'Infinity' could be defined as 99999, INT32 MAX, etc. depending on the type the user desires.)

For those also familiar with rust as I am, the equivalent trait to what I am trying to define as a typeclass would be:

```rust
trait NavNode : Eq + Hash + Sized {
    type Distance: Ord + Add;
    
    const INFINITY: Self::Distance;
    const ZERO: Self::Distance;
    
    fn heuristic(a: Self, b: Self) -> Self::Distance;
    fn neighbors(self) -> Vec<Self>;
}
```

The nearest to an implementation I've managed to make is this, but I've found no way to constrain the associated `Distance` type to be `Num` and `Ord`, and the compiler does not like my definitions for the `zero` and `infinity` constants or usage of `Distance a`, which it confusingly seems to insist ought to be some `Distance a0`.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class (Eq a, Hashable a) => NavNode a where
    type Distance a :: * -- How to tell it it's Num, Ord?
    heuristic   :: a -> a -> Distance a
    neighbours  :: a -> [a]
    zero        :: Distance a
    infinity    :: Distance a
```

Comment: Does it have to be a typeclass? I could easily imagine wanting two different `neighbours` or `heuristic` functions for a single type, which suggests to me you want a record instead, e.g. `data SearchGraph a d = SearchGraph { heuristic :: a -> a -> d, neighbours :: a -> [a] }` and `aStar :: (Eq a, Hashable a, Eq d, Bounded d) => SearchGraph a d -> a -> [a]` or something like that. (It seems much more reasonable to me that `zero` and `infinity` be unique per distance type, so that one probably makes sense to keep as a typeclass. `Bounded` may not be the right choice for that class.)

Comment: @DanielWagner That's a fair point, it would absolutely make sense to allow for different heuristic and neighbour calculations for a single type. I did a similar thing when I implemented this in F# earlier the same day I attempted it in Haskell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of code that compiles. I have removed `Hashable` for simplicity, but you can add it back in your real code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

import Data.Kind

class (Eq a, Ord (Distance a), Num (Distance a)) => NavNode a where
    type Distance a :: Type -- The line above requires this to be Ord and Num
    heuristic   :: a -> a -> Distance a
    neighbours  :: a -> [a]
    zero        :: Distance a
    infinity    :: Distance a

-- Dummy instance: it's nonsense, but it shows the main ideas.
instance NavNode String where
    type Distance String = Int
    heuristic x y = abs (length x - length y)
    neighbours x = [x]
    zero = 0
    infinity = 1000

main :: IO ()
main = print (infinity @String)
```

Note the `@String` in the last line, which is mandatory so to specify the actual instance. Indeed, multiple types can have `Int` as their associated distance type, so we have to specify it to disambiguate.

Comment: I'm curious - Is AllowAmbiguousTypes necessary and good practice for this kind of typeclass? Writing something "ambiguous" never sounds like a particularly good thing in other contexts! Or am I forced to use it because I'm taking an un-haskell-ish approach to things?

Comment: @EthanMcTague It's needed and it is indeed a good extension (despite the name). By default, Haskell rejects the constants `zero :: Distance a` since that breaks type inference: from `zero :: Int` we can not infer the type `a` since it's possible that `Distance String = Distance Bool = Int`, so `a` is not uniquely determined. Before ambiguous types we used proxies and tagged types which were less convenient; nowadays we simply use `zero @String` to disambiguate.